# Formulas for Schrödinger unitary groups of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $\Omega$ an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the Hilbert space $X=L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$ and the Schrödinger operator $A=i\Delta$ defined on the domain $D(A)=H^2(\Omega)$. 
Is there any explicit formula for the unitary group $U(t)$ generated by the operator $A$, in the case $\Omega$ bounded and in the case  $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$? My intuition tells me that if $\Omega$ is bounded, then it must be something like
$$U(t)=\sum_n e^{it\lambda_n}P_n,$$ 
with $P_n$ being projections. For $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$ it must be something like the Bochner integral
$$U(t)=\int e^{it\lambda}P_{\lambda}d\lambda.$$
But I don't know if such formulas exist.

Comment: You can use the Fourier transform in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @mathematician Thanks, do you know any reference where I can find this ?

Comment: Maybe a better keyword would have been "fundamental solution".  In $\mathbb{R}^n$, $U(t)f_0(x)=\int(4πit)^{−n/2}e^{i|y|^2/4t}f_0(x-y)\,dy$.

Comment: But for general Ω matters are more complicated. As to your expression for $U(t)$, given that $-Δ$ defines the self-adjoint Hamiltonian $H=∫λP(dλ)$, the formula is $U(t)=∫e^{itλ}P(dλ)$. Here $P(dλ)$ is the projection valued measure associated with the spectral decomposition of $H$. See for instance the volumes of Reed and Simon for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a densely-defined selfadjoint operator $A$ on a Hilbert Space $X$, the spectral theorem gives you
$$
                     Ax = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lambda dE(\lambda)x,
$$
where you can interpret the above through measure theory, or as a Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to the non-decreasing selfadjoint projection-valued function $E(\lambda)$, where $E(-\infty)=0$ and $E(+\infty)=I$. This is John von Neumann's Spectral Theorem that he developed for Quantum Mechanics. In either case,
$$
                   U(t)x=e^{itA}x = \int e^{it\lambda}dE(\lambda)x.
$$
That's what you have here after you correctly define the operator domain to include boundary restrictions. The unconstrained $A=-\Delta$ on $\mathcal{D}(A)=H^{2}$ is not selfadjoint on a bounded region without restricting the domain to functions satisfying some type of homogeneous boundary condition. For example, $\mathcal{D}(A)=H^{2}\cap H^{1}_{0}$ is a common restriction. Von Neumann also described an abstract theory of defining conditions to do this.

Comment: Thank you again! I don't know a reference where  I can find those formulas.

Comment: @user50618 : This is the classical version of the Spectral Theorem for Unbounded Selfadjoint Operators on a Hilbert Space. Many Functional Analysis texts will cover such a topic.

Comment: I want this formula just to check if the function $t\mapsto\int_{0}^{t}U(s)xds$
  is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$
 . For $A=a\in\mathbb{R}$
 , $\int_{0}^{t}U(s)xds=\int_{0}^{t}e^{isa}xds=\frac{1}{ia}\left(e^{ita}-1\right)$
  is bounded. So I asked myself if we can do such calculus for the group $U(t)$.

Comment: You can write $\int_{0}^{s}U(t)x\,dt=\int \int_{0}^{s}e^{i\lambda t}\,dt\,dE(\lambda)x=\int \frac{1}{i\lambda}(e^{is\lambda}-1)dE(\lambda)x$, and you can see that $\int_{0}^{s}U(t)x\,dt\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ for all $t > 0$, which is a well-known and interesting fact.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if $s\mapsto \int \frac{1}{i\lambda}(e^{is\lambda}-1)dE(\lambda)x$ is bounded with respect to $s$ ?

Comment: For the functional calculus $\|\int f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)x\|^{2}=\int |f(\lambda)|^{2}\,d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2}$ and $\int d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}$, which does it for you. In fact, $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ iff $\int \lambda^{2}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2} < \infty$. In that case, $Ax=\int \lambda dE(\lambda)x$, and $\|Ax\|^{2}=\int \lambda^{2}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2}$. If $F$ is bounded, then $F(A)x=\int F(\lambda)dE(\lambda)x$ is a bounded linear operator and satisfies $F(A)\int f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)x=\int F(\lambda)f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)x$.

Comment: Those are some great tools !! So in this case for our $f(\lambda)=\frac{1}{i\lambda}\left(e^{it\lambda}-1\right)$, the problem is whether $\int \frac{1}{|\lambda|^2}d\|E(\lambda)x \|^2$ exist or not. I guess this requires $A=i\Delta$ to be invertible, but I don't know if this is true for $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @user50618 : It does with a numerator $(e^{it\lambda}-1)$ which vanishes at $\lambda=0$. But you also get $\int_{0}^{s}U(t)x\,dt$ in the domain of $A$ because you can multiply the integrand of $\int \frac{1}{i\lambda}(e^{it\lambda}-1)dE(\lambda)x$ by $\lambda$ and the spectral integral is still finite.

Comment: Ah you are right !! Thank you for your consistent contribution to the website, I am going to learn some functional calculus, it is cool !!!

Comment: @user50618 : Indeed. :)

Comment: $\left|\int_{0}^{t}U(s)xds\right|^{2}=\left|\int\frac{1}{i \lambda}\left(e^{it \lambda}-1\right)dE(\lambda)x\right|^{2}=\int\left|\frac{1}{i\lambda}\left(e^{it\lambda}-1\right)\right|^{2}d\left|E(\lambda)x\right|^{2}$. I think that we cannot bounded the quantity $\left|\frac{1}{i\lambda}\left(e^{it\lambda}-1\right)\right|^{2}$ by a constant independent of both $\lambda$ and $t$. By the way for the operator $A=i\Delta$ with $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, does the spectral integral $A=\int\lambda dE(\lambda)$ scans only the spectrum of $A$ i.e $Ax=\int_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}\lambda dE(\lambda)x$ ?

Comment: The problem lies when $\lambda$ is near $0$, it is true that we can bound $\left|\frac{1}{i\lambda}\left(e^{it\lambda}-1\right)\right|^{2}$ by a constant $M$, but the constant $M$ must depend in $t$, $M=M_t$ and $M_t$ explodes when $t\to +\infty$.

Comment: @user50618 : For a fixed $t$, the expression is bounded in $\lambda$, but the bound can change with $t$, as you noted. I think your analysis is correct. However, if the spectrum is bounded below by some $\lambda_{0} > 0$, then $|\frac{1}{i\lambda}(e^{it\lambda}-1)| \le 2/\lambda_{0}$ remains uniformly bounded in $t$. This would normally be the case for bounded regions, but not for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. This may be the answer you want.

Comment: I was just about to ask a question whether we can find a differential skew-adjoint operator $A$ with a spectrum $\sigma(A)=i(-\infty,-1]$ to separate spectrum from $0$ unlike the operator $i\Delta$ which has the spectrum $i(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the Fourier transform implements the Spectral Theorem. And it looks like a problem in that case. There you have $\|\int_{0}^{t}U(s)f\,ds\|=\|\hat{f}(\lambda)(e^{it\lambda^{2}}-1)/\lambda^{2}\|_{L^{2}}$.

Comment: I have a lot of questions, but I feel it is better to post them as questions so everyone can found them easily when he ask similar questions. So I started by this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895205/skew-adjoint-differential-operator-b-with-spectrum-sigmab-i-infty-1