# Skew-adjoint differential operator $B$ with spectrum $\sigma(B)=i(-\infty,-1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Consider the Hilbert space $X=L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ and the Schrödinger operator $A=i\Delta$ defined on the domain $D(A)=H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It is known that the spectrum of $A$ is $\sigma(A)=i(-\infty,0]:=\{i\omega,\ \omega\leq0 \}$. I am just asking if there exists a skew-adjoint differential operator $B$ with a spectrum $\sigma(B)=i(-\infty,-1]$.

Comment: If you allow complex coefficients, then $i\Delta$. If you don't allow complex coefficients, and if you use constant coefficient differential operators, then you'll need odd powers of derivatives, and the spectrum isn't likely to be confined to a half-line. Half-lines and quadratics go together nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an intuition for the much simpler case of finite dimension.
Let $A$ be any matrix and $v$ an associated eigenvector, i.e. $Av = \lambda v$. Then $(A-I)v = Av-v = (\lambda-1)v$, and thus $\sigma(A-I)= \sigma(A)-1$.

And now an attempt for infinite dimension, suppose that $(A-i\lambda I)$ is not invertible for every $\lambda \in (-\infty, 0]$ but then $(A-i(\lambda+1)I) = ((A-iI)-i\lambda)$ is not invertible for every $\lambda \in (-\infty,-1]$, i.e. $\sigma(A-iI)=i (-\infty,-1]$.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be a problem for an operator to be skew adjoint and invertible at the same time for some unknown reason.

Comment: @user50618 "for some unknown reason" :), it's often like that.